# Is there much overhead with HTTP uploads?

Tags: http, browser, encoding, upload, file-upload

I have files often uploaded via browser and maybe considering using another method to make uploads faster.

When a file is uploaded via browser, is there much overhead due to encoding?

Do you know how much?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only overhead are the HTTP headers and the multipart/form-data MIME format; all of this is static (see RFC2616 and RFC2388).

Comment: Someone said that Base 64 encoding is used. Then they erased their answer, so I guess they realized they are wrong. 
If the file is transfered as raw data, are http transfers as good as rsync?

Comment: rsync usually just transfers binary diffs; that's something you can't do over HTTP unless the server supports something like RFC 3229 or the HTTP PATCH method with a yet-to-be-defined payload format.